# Rearrange Components in Visual Studio Outline

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I noticed you can rearrange Controls in the outline window of Visual Studio 2010 like this:

[image]

However if you select a Component there is no way to move it up or down:

[image]

Those buttons get disabled.

I am wondering how you could rearrange them and maybe sort them alphabetically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Components are threated completely different than controls in visual studio for some dark reason. You will have to drag them where you want them in the form designer and when you are lucky they will stay on that position.

Comment: Components appear at the end of list in the order they are added to form. Take a look at `Form1.Designer.cs` and in `InitializeComponent` see the components are instantiated in the same order that you dropped them on form and the same order that you can see in *Document Outline* window.  You can change the order in code (not recommended.) Also you can use the combobox in `Properties` windows to see them alphabetically.